# 'The idea how/ the idea of how/ the idea that how' a recessive gene might become dominant

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, clauses, that

What *word* should come in place of (?) in the sentence below? Personally, I would use *of* or *that*.But I am not sure if these are correct or if I should forgo any word at all there. I would appreciate the logic behind your answer(s). Also, what clause is introduced by *how* in this example sentence?

*The scientist put forward the idea (?) how a recessive gene might become dominant in a later generation*.

Comment: Why use a fancy construction like _put forward the idea_? It has all sorts of restrictions and presuppositions, as you found out. Why not just use _said that_ or _told us that_ or _showed us how_ or _demonstrated the ways that_?

Comment: @John Lawler: Thanks. Actually I read a similar sentence a while back where the writer had continued the sentence as... _put forward the idea how..._. It struck me as iffy and that's why I asked it here. I might rephrase it like you suggested. Still, may I know why _that_ or perhaps some other word is required in the sentence?

Comment: I would advise you to drop the term 'noun clause', even though it is still used in some trad grammars. Noun is a part of speech like "house", "car", "Fred" etc. The classification of finite subordinate clauses is based on their internal form rather than spurious analogies with the parts of speech. Note that only noun phrases, not clauses, can be appositives.

Comment: Thank you very much, @BillJ!

Comment: Incidentally, I'm not sure why you feel that there should be a word between "idea" and "how". It seems to me that in your example "how" is being used as an informal variant of the subordinator "that", and more formally we would have "The scientist put forward the idea that a recessive gene might become dominant in a later generation".

Comment: I thought you said earlier the idea of how... is okay. Or is it that I should simply write the idea how...? I agree with @HotLicks and you that put forward the idea that is a better version. I just wanted to know how to write this _how version_ of the sentence properly.

Comment: I misunderstood your original question. As I said, "how" is here an informal variant of "that", and is not recommended.

Comment: Many thanks! One final question: Going by the above comments, is the sentence _The fact how the answer came to George's mind startled us all_ is as questionable as the above sentence and so I should rephrase it thus: _The fact that the answer..._ In nutshell, _the [Noun] how_ combo has to be avoided at all costs. Am I right, @BillJ?

Comment: Yes, you should rephrase it that way. I would certainly avoid using "how". The reason is that "how" is not a subordinator, so it should not be used to introduce subordinate clauses.

Answer (score 2):

I would rephrase your sentence, separating "the idea" from "the mechanism".

The scientist put forward the idea of a recessive gene becoming dominant in a later generation, and explained how it might happen.

Comment: Thank you but isn't it almost the gospel of books on style to _cut_,_cut_,_cut_? Your sentence circumvents the problem by rephrasing my sentence but rambles a bit. Don't you think so @Centaurus?

Comment: If you cut, cut, cut until it is incomprehensible, this is not good style. Your text should be long enough that it's easily understood, but no longer.